# Why is the screen blank after boot?

Tags: centos, boot, grub2, nvidia, display

Screen blank when booting up CentOS 2.7 GRUB. During the booting process, I see activity scrolling down the screen. Then my screen goes blank. I have a NIVIDIA graphics card, which may be causing the problem. In the setparms, I specified ... nomodeset vga=789 splash. The following is the exact boot code:

setparams 'CentOS Linux (3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64) 7 (Core)'

load_video set gfxpayload=keep insmod gzio insmod part_gpt insmod ext2

set root='hd0,gpt2'

if [x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root \ --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2\ --hing-baremetal=ahcio,gpt2 27483794-8c21-\ 428f-951e-315bce52e222 else search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root \ 27483794-8c21-428f-951e-315bce52e222 fi

linuxefi /vmlinux-3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 root= \ /dev/mapper/centos-roo ro crashkernel=auto \ rd.lvm.lv=centos/root rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap \ nomodeset rhgb quiet LANG=en.UTF8 \

initrdefi /initramfs-3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64.img

Comment: are you certain that the screen is completely blank?

Comment: Sounds to me like the boot finished but gdm crashed or failed to start. Control-alt-F2 to get a tty to log in and look at logs. If you turned off modesetting because you installed the 3rd party nvidia driver, I’d check to see if you broke something there.